# How do I access a shared folder using credentials other than the ones I logged in with?

Tags: windows-7, security

I have a lab full of Windows 7 machines, and a shared login (user360) that all my students use.  I also have a shared folder that they can all have read/write access to (for moving files around easily).

My problem is that I also want to be able to create a shared folder for each student for submitting assignments.  I can set up a shared folder with permissions for just a single user, and not the 'user360' account.

The problem is, when I'm logged in as user360, and I try to open the 'StudentA', Windows never asks me for alternate credentials, it just refuses access because the user360 account is not allowed access.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need to do is to have the shared folder mapped on each computer, which allows you to use different credentials.

In My Computer, click on Tools (hidden by default, show by pressing ALT), Map Network Drive, and there, type in the path for the drive and underneath, click on "Connect using different credentials"

Good luck!

EDIT:

For the credentials to be accepted the correct format is for the username is:

\\SERVERNAME\username

Then just the normal password for the account.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I try this, the credentials I have for the student are being rejected.  I'm not sure why as they're definitely valid ( I can log in to the server machine directly using them).  Something very odd is happening :(

Comment: See the edit to my reply for the correct format.

Answer (score 4):

In Win7. While accessing Shared Folder with different credential still FAILED and DENIED even using correct USERNAME and appropriate password, make sure your 'Credential Manager' is free from inappropriate cached.
[image: 'Remove from fault' or 'Edit' to actualize your appropriate credential]

Thank you. :)